# Transit accessible parking lots near Amsterdam

Tags: automobiles, netherlands, amsterdam

I'm planning to travel to Amsterdam by car to visit the city center.  My understanding that parking in the city center for a day is both difficult and expensive.  Are there any free or lower cost parking lots near Amsterdam that are transit accessible in which one could reasonably expect to be able to park for a day?

Comment: There are a number of Park & Ride locations, from which direction are you travelling? https://www.iamsterdam.com/en/plan-your-trip/getting-around/parking

Comment: @Traveller How can I find a complete list of these park and ride locations? In my particular case, from the southwest.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk [Here it is](https://www.iamsterdam.com/en/plan-your-trip/getting-around/parking/park-and-ride)

Comment: @Relaxed If you make that an answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a P+R car park. [More details and a brochure with a map are available from iamsterdam.com](https://www.iamsterdam.com/en/plan-your-trip/getting-around/parking/park-and-ride)